# How do I stop this Windows Update Icon of Terror in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Today, an obnoxious red dot icon appeared in the Notification area on my Windows 10 computer. It's Windows Update, pestering me to install updates.

It doesn't go away if I "schedule another day".

It doesn't let me hide or close it.

I've restarted the computer ("Update and restart") and it's still there.

It repeatedly says "Updates available" and makes me download them, but then fails to install them and stays around and distracts my eyes constantly, refusing to go away.

I'm honestly way past the point where I have any energy left to troubleshoot this kind of nonsense which just "happens" to my machine without me doing anything or asking for it in any way.

Right now, it says (again -- it seems to just throw away the install/patch/update file every time it fails to apply it):

> Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.
>   2020-05 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1903 for x64-based Systems (KB4556799)

I don't really know why I even bother asking about this. I'm sure I won't like the solution, which is probably going to require me to test all kinds of things and stuff. I just want it to go away and stop pestering me with the icon. I have done nothing "fancy" which would possibly explain that this update (whatever it is) fails to apply.

I'm still months away from my annual Windows reinstallation nightmare, and I can only pray that I'm going to be forced to go through that horrible ordeal again just to get rid of this nonsensical issue.

Comment: From what I understand, you're still running 1903, and Windows is offering to install the latest version, that's only beginning to be deployed, aka 2005. It's up to you to postpone, or even decline to install it, but it'll keep pestering you until you do, or install some third-party that'll ultimately break down your PC anyway, so think about it as an urge to puke you know you can fight only for so long until you finally hug the porcelain god, and take the plunge. That's my advice, but then I'll probably be in your position in a couple days, and you'll laugh at me with mirthful glee...

Comment: "Icon Of Terror" Lol, pretty much describes Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried an alternative OS, e.g. Linux? *You* control updates. In Ubuntu, updates are once or twice a week, but take <5 minutes... when you want to apply them.

Comment: The update you referred to just came out today and installed just fine on my machines.  Perhaps you are running some software that caused it not to install. I am 3 and half years into this machine I am typing on and yet to have to reinstall Windows

Answer (score 0):

This depends on having Windows 10 Pro or higher; if you have Win 10 Home, you're out of luck.

Launch Windows Update by clicking the *Start*  button, then select *Settings* > *Update & Security*  > *Windows Update*  and choose *Advanced Options*.

Set the *Defer Updates* spin box to **365** then change the *Branch Readiness Level* to **Semi-Annual Channel** from Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted).

(Until Microsoft breaks this again.)